# Math.Random not working correctly typescript

Tags: javascript, math, typescript, random, ionic2

Simple question but I can't find the answer, I'm pretty bad with maths. The thing is that i have this formula to generate a random number.

```
  numRandomed: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  public randomize(min, max) {
    console.log("minimo: " + min);
    console.log("maximo: " + max);

    this.numRandomed = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    console.log(this.numRandomed);
  }
```

And the View

```
<ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Min Number</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]='minNumber'></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Max Number</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]='maxNumber'></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <button ion-button (click)='randomize(minNumber,maxNumber)'>Randomize!</button>
  <p>{{ numRandomed }}</p>
```

But the random number is always lower than the min number, isn't inside the range, I don't know why...

Any clue?? Thank you!!

Comment: Why do you add a field `numRandomed` to the `randomize` prototype when you are not using the `randomize` class/object and immediately return the value of that field?

Comment: I'm using that variable in the view, with {{ numRandomed }}
And I'm calling the function by a button in the view.

Comment: Is this some kind of closure and are you sure that you are using the correct form for a closure? Is it not necessary to define `let me=this;` outside and then assign to `me.numRandomed`?

Comment: How can i paste my code here? I will put it entirely, so you can see what i have exactly.

Comment: I added my code to the main post.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code in node.js and it works well.

This code:

```
function randomize(min, max) {
    console.log("minimo: " + min);
    console.log("maximo: " + max);

    let x;

    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min));
    console.log(x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min));
}

randomize(10,20)
randomize(10,20)
randomize(10,20)
randomize(10,20)
randomize(10,20)
randomize(10,20)
```

Is having this output

```
minimo: 10
maximo: 20
20
11
minimo: 10
maximo: 20
17
13
minimo: 10
maximo: 20
18
20
minimo: 10
maximo: 20
13
11
minimo: 10
maximo: 20
18
10
minimo: 10
maximo: 20
12
16
```

I would suggest, that you overwrite numRandomed at some point or return value of randomize method is not used or something like this.